# Spring WebServiceTemplate SOAPAction missing in HTTP Header

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws

I am having difficulty in calling a SOAP 1.2 WebService via Spring-ws WebServiceTemplate.  The request being made is missing SOAPAction in Http Header and the server throws an error with "Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action."  I was able to figure out SOAP Action was missing by monitoring through wireshark. I am also not behind any proxy.

I have made sure that the SOAP XML I am trying to send is valid by running the request through TCP Mon ( tool like SOAP UI) and was able to get response.

Here is my spring config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
    <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
 <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
<property name="defaultUri" value="https://ecomapi.networksolutions.com/soapservice.asmx" />
<property name="messageSender">
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender" />     </property>
</bean>
```

And this is my java code:

```
            public void simpleSendAndReceive() {
            try{
            StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(MESSAGE));
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
            SoapActionCallback actionCallBack = new SoapActionCallback("https://ecomapi.networksolutions.com/soapservice.asmx") {
                public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage msg) {
                    SoapMessage smsg = (SoapMessage)msg;
                    smsg.setSoapAction("http://networksolutions.com/ReadOrder");
                }
            };
            webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(
                    "https://ecomapi.networksolutions.com/soapservice.asmx",
                     source,
                     new SoapActionCallback("http://networksolutions.com/ReadOrder"),
     //                      actionCallBack,
                     result);


            System.out.println(source.getInputStream().toString());
            System.out.println(result.getWriter().toString());

            }catch (SoapFaultClientException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getFaultCode());
                System.out.println(e.getFaultStringOrReason());
                System.out.println(e.fillInStackTrace().getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch (WebServiceIOException we) {
                System.out.println(we.getRootCause());
            }
        }
```

Comment: You seem to be setting SOAP Action headers multiple ways here right - using `actionCallBack`, explicitly using `new SoapActionCallback..`, are both approaches not working?

Comment: Thats correct. Both the approaches give the same error back.

Comment: You require a `http://networksolutions.com/ReadOrder` header right - what header do you see over the wire using wireshark. Just want to ensure that you are not sending `https://ecomapi.networksolutions.com/soapservice.asmx`. This is a simple tool to capture what is going back and forth - http://sourceforge.net/projects/nettool/

Comment: I have attached two screen shots that show the differences in the HTTP headers. First is the screenshot for the request I am sending from TCP Mon ![TCPMon Request Header](http://tinypic.com/r/2e4w0hl/6)  and the second is the request made from java.![Java  Request Header](http://tinypic.com/r/5wyog2/6) 

 If you notice, SOAPAction is missing in the header for the java request.

Comment: I am not able to replicate your behavior, sorry. I tried the same webserviceTemplate API that you have used - with explicit SOAPActionCallback the way you have provided and it works cleanly for me, the SOAPAction header appears in the header. Can you confirm the version of Spring-WS - I am using 2.1.0

Comment: I am using spring-ws 2.0.0. Here is the relevant entry in pom.xml:

    <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Okay, may not harm upgrading to Spring-WS 2.1.0 and trying once more

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I traced it back to a bug in the 1.3.2 version of the com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl implementation (http://java.net/jira/browse/SAAJ-37).
 I upgraded to the 1.3.19 version and all was fine.

**The Issue**:-

Before writing the request to the output stream, the saveChanges() method is called.  The 1.3.2 version of this class  was overwriting the 'Content-Type' request header in it's implementation of the 'saveChanges' method.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which was due to the namespace of the XmlSchema annotation in the package-info.java file being different from what the soap service I was trying to call expected. This resulted from me using xjc to generate the jaxb request and response objects from a xsd that I had sewn together from the wsdl parts plus the xsd header from a previous service I was interfacing so it was a pure cut and paste error on my part but the previous answer on here about the namespace was what clued me in to my error quickly.

Answer (score 0):

SOAPAction is mandatory only in SOAP 1.1, see [section Content Type](http://www.hadleynet.org/marc/whatsnew.html).

> The SOAP 1.1 mandatory SOAPAction HTTP header has been removed in SOAP 1.2. In its place is an optional action parameter on the application/soap+xml media type.